# Trying to create noise image with noise, numpy, and Image

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm trying to create some perlin noise images in python and having a bit of a problem. I get an exception when I run my little script. I'm clearly not grasping something about the usage of the Image module as everything I try results in a ValueError exception with the message "buffer is not large enough"

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import numpy
from noise import pnoise2, snoise2
import Image


octaves = 1
freq = 16.0 * octaves
y_max = 5
x_max = 5
imarray = [[0 for x in range(y_max)] for x in range(x_max)]
totalcount = 0

for y in range(y_max):
    for x in range(x_max):
        val = "%s\n" % int(snoise2(x / freq, y / freq, octaves) * 127.0 + 128.0)
        imarray[y][x] = val
        totalcount += 1

arr = numpy.asarray(imarray).astype('uint8')

im = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGBA')
im.save('./blah.png')
```

And the exception I'm getting:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1184)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2407, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1798, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/u4234/source/systools/load/noise_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    im = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGBA')
  File "/Users/u4234/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg/Image.py", line 1902, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
  File "/Users/u4234/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg/Image.py", line 1853, in frombuffer
    core.map_buffer(data, size, decoder_name, None, 0, args)
ValueError: buffer is not large enough

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a color or a gray scale image?

Comment: It's supposed to be in color. Though in this example I'm only doing one color at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking `PIL` to create a new `'RGBA'` image, which requires 4 channels, but you are passing only a bidimensional array, e.g. one channel.

As illustrated by the following, given these arrays:

```
arr1 = numpy.zeros((5, 5), dtype=numpy.uint8)  # A single 5x5 channel
arr2 = numpy.zeros((5, 5, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)  # 3 5x5 channels
```

Create a grayscale `'L'` image:

```
im = Image.fromarray(arr1, 'L')  # OK
im = Image.fromarray(arr2, 'L')  # ValueError: Too many dimensions.
```

Create a color image without alpha channel `'RGB'`:

```
im = Image.fromarray(arr1, 'RGB')  # ValueError: not enough image data
im = Image.fromarray(arr2, 'RGB')  # OK
```

Note the usage of *RGB* mode, since probably you don't care about the alpha channel, otherwise simply add other dimension to the `numpy.zeros` constructor.

---

You could rewrite your code to be,

```
arr = numpy.zeros((5, 5, 1), dtype=numpy.uint8)

y_max, x_max, channels = arr.shape

for y in range(y_max):
    for x in range(x_max):
        val = int(snoise2(x / freq, y / freq, octaves) * 127.0 + 128.0)
        arr[y,x,0] = val

im = Image.fromarray(arr, 'L')
im.save('./blah.png')
```

To generate a grayscale image.

Comment: That was it :) Thanks memoselyk. If I could upvote you I would. But I don't have enough reputation yet. Will a hearty "thank you" do?

Comment: Sure, you are welcome! BTW... There is a [`numpy.function`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html#numpy.fromfunction) which could simplify your noise generator, if it's a function of the image coordinates.